# 16.04.1 LTS server x graphical interface Fails to start

Tags: desktop-environments

Please give advice I have read so far this is often due to graphical card issues.  All my upgrades are up to date.  But can't get through boot up without using grub utility otherwise freezes on Ubuntu screen.  When I do get on there is no server x graphical interface.

Video card video memory test 
Vendor uEFI
Tested 63.93mb
Pass

I have reformatted and installed from cd.  Fixed issue so unfortunately not graphics card issue which could mean it's a upgrade issue.